# mapdeck R when using fill_colour the session crashes in Rstudio

Tags: r, mapdeck

As the title says when I use the `fill_colour` parameter my session crashes.

For example if I take from the [Colours section of the mapdeck site](https://symbolixau.github.io/mapdeck/articles/colours.html) and run

```
library(mapdeck)
library(sf)

sf <- spatialwidget::widget_melbourne

mapdeck() %>%
  add_polygon(
    data = sf
    , fill_colour = "SA2_NAME"
  )
```

Then the system crashes with "R Session Aborted"

If I amend the above to just

```
library(mapdeck)
library(sf)

sf <- spatialwidget::widget_melbourne

mapdeck() %>%
  add_polygon(
    data = sf
  )
```

then the plot comes out without an error.

If I go to the logs from the help menu in Rstudio then there's nothing about the crash.

What should I be checking, removing, reinstalling, etc?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] units_0.8-0        dplyr_1.0.9        jsonify_1.2.1      RColorBrewer_1.1-3 sf_1.0-8           mapdeck_0.3.4      stringr_1.4.0      arrow_8.0.0       
 [9] webshot2_0.1.0     ggplot2_3.3.6      glue_1.6.2         magrittr_2.0.3     flextable_0.7.0    data.table_1.14.2  lubridate_1.8.0   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3        class_7.3-20        ps_1.7.0            assertthat_0.2.1    digest_0.6.29       utf8_1.2.2          R6_2.5.1            evaluate_0.15      
 [9] e1071_1.7-9         pillar_1.7.0        gdtools_0.2.4       rlang_1.0.2         uuid_1.1-0          rmarkdown_2.14      htmlwidgets_1.5.4   bit_4.0.4          
[17] munsell_0.5.0       proxy_0.4-26        compiler_4.2.0      xfun_0.31           pkgconfig_2.0.3     systemfonts_1.0.4   base64enc_0.1-3     htmltools_0.5.2    
[25] spatialwidget_0.2.3 websocket_1.4.1     tidyselect_1.1.2    tibble_3.1.7        fansi_1.0.3         crayon_1.5.1        withr_2.5.0         later_1.3.0        
[33] grid_4.2.0          jsonlite_1.8.0      gtable_0.3.0        lifecycle_1.0.1     DBI_1.1.2           scales_1.2.0        KernSmooth_2.23-20  zip_2.2.0          
[41] cli_3.3.0           stringi_1.7.6       promises_1.2.0.1    xml2_1.3.3          ellipsis_0.3.2      generics_0.1.2      vctrs_0.4.1         tools_4.2.0        
[49] bit64_4.0.5         officer_0.4.2       purrr_0.3.4         processx_3.5.3      fastmap_1.1.0       yaml_2.3.5          chromote_0.1.0      colorspace_2.0-3   
[57] classInt_0.4-3      knitr_1.39
```

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76334903/changing-stroke-or-fill-color-causes-mapdeck-to-crash-in-r

Comment: @SymbolixAU The SO time machine was broken that day in 2022 so I couldn't have found that question that would be written in 2023.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague and I have encountered this issue on two different machines.  **mapdeck** crashes the latest versions of R when you try to use things like `fill_colour`.

Reverting to R version 4.1.2 seems to restore correct behaviour.

Comment: It seems to have to do with the C libraries in windows.  It runs fine in linux.