# Changing stroke or fill color causes mapdeck to crash in R

Tags: r, shiny, mapdeck

I'm simply trying to change stroke and fill colors of my polygons, lines or points in R using mapdeck. When I try to adjust these parameters it causes R to crash, throwing the following error and requiring me to terminate my r session:

```
Registered S3 method overwritten by 'jsonify':
  method     from    
  print.json jsonlite
```

If I don't change the colors, it renders my data as expected. I've tried using older and the newest R version, uninstalling R, and updating packages. Does anyone have any ideas what's going on? Running on Windows 11, see my session info below.

```
library(mapdeck)
set_token(TOKEN) 
mapdeck() %>%
  add_path(
    data = roads
    , stroke_colour = "RIGHT_LOC"  #When this line is commented out it works perfectly fine
  )
```

Session Info:

```
 sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] mapdeck_0.3.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.2.0   remotes_2.4.2     
 [3] purrr_1.0.1        sf_1.0-12         
 [5] jsonify_1.2.2      vctrs_0.6.2       
 [7] generics_0.1.3     miniUI_0.1.1.1    
 [9] htmltools_0.5.5    usethis_2.1.6     
[11] yaml_2.3.7         utf8_1.2.3        
[13] rlang_1.1.1        pkgbuild_1.4.0    
[15] e1071_1.7-13       pillar_1.9.0      
[17] later_1.3.1        urlchecker_1.0.1  
[19] glue_1.6.2         DBI_1.1.3         
[21] sessioninfo_1.2.2  lifecycle_1.0.3   
[23] stringr_1.5.0      devtools_2.4.5    
[25] htmlwidgets_1.6.2  memoise_2.0.1     
[27] callr_3.7.3        fastmap_1.1.1     
[29] httpuv_1.6.11      ps_1.7.5          
[31] class_7.3-21       fansi_1.0.4       
[33] Rcpp_1.0.10        KernSmooth_2.23-20
[35] xtable_1.8-4       promises_1.2.0.1  
[37] classInt_0.4-9     cachem_1.0.8      
[39] pkgload_1.3.2      jsonlite_1.8.4    
[41] mime_0.12          fs_1.6.2          
[43] digest_0.6.31      stringi_1.7.12    
[45] processx_3.8.1     dplyr_1.1.2       
[47] shiny_1.7.4        grid_4.2.3        
[49] cli_3.6.1          tools_4.2.3       
[51] magrittr_2.0.3     proxy_0.4-27      
[53] tibble_3.2.1       profvis_0.3.8     
[55] crayon_1.5.2       sfheaders_0.4.2   
[57] pkgconfig_2.0.3    ellipsis_0.3.2    
[59] prettyunits_1.1.1  rstudioapi_0.14   
[61] R6_2.5.1           units_0.8-2       
[63] compiler_4.2.3  

sapply (c ("geojsonsf", "spatialwidget", "googlePolylines", "mapdeck"),
+           packageVersion)
$geojsonsf
[1] 2 0 3

$spatialwidget
[1] 0 2 3

$googlePolylines
[1] 0 8 3

$mapdeck
[1] 0 3 4
```

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/mapdeck/issues/359) - but I don't have access to Windows to test it, and the CRAN checks aren't throwing any errors. So it's really difficult to debug.

Comment: there is [a fix](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/mapdeck/issues/359#issuecomment-1642622489) on it's way

Comment: This was one of the big reasons I switched to doing everything in WSL instead of Windows directly.